# Modeling Mercedes Star

Tags: modeling

[image]

I'm modelling a Mercedes badge in Blender 2.92.

What is the best way of modelling the tristar? I've tried several ways like three NURBS paths joined then extruded along a triangle for one, but cannot get the join at the center right.

Comment: Can you explain what you don't like and what exactly is the problem? You wrote *"...cannot get the join at the centre right"*. But in the screenshot it looks ok, no?  The connection to the outer ring differs a bit...

Comment: If this q. doesn't get reopened... the junction at the center is a tetrahedron.

Answer (score 2):

I would take the following workflow:

1. Create a small “circle” with only three vertices. [image: triangle]
2. Fill the circle, and extrude a bit. You will now have a right solid. [image: right solid]
3. Merge the vertices of the extrusion at center. You will now have what would be a cone if the bottom were a circle and not a triangle. [image: cone]
4. Select the three triangular faces generated in step 2 (the “sides of the mountain” as it were), and “Extrude Individual.” Note that they will come out at an angle. You will now have something that looks like an impeller prototype. [image: prototype]
5. Merge the three faces’ extrusion vertices at center, **one face at a time**. You will now have a cross between the prototype and the finished Mercedes-Benz logo. [image: cross]
6. Move the three merge result vertices to be coplanar with the original circle. You should now know that you have modeled the logo of one of the safest cars on the road (British accent). [image: finish]

Comment: Sorry, can't make this work. Perhaps the direction of the extrusion/s are making me go wrong?

Comment: @pchis1 ahh. Make sure it’s “extrude individual” and “along normals”

Comment: I'll try that. But what's the point of the extrude in step 2? and does it make any differernce if positive or negative z direction?

Comment: Nope,still can't get it to work. I only have a choice of 'extrude individual" or "extrude faces along normals' . . .

Comment: @pchis1 I’ve had to use the search engine to get to it, but it does exist. Extruding in step two is so you don’t end up with something two dimensional. If you’re creating a cylinder instead of a circle in step one, step two is void.

Comment: @pchis1 I’m sorry, “along normal“ is an automatic default orientation of “Extrude individual.“ Do that.

Comment: Could I trouble you for some screenshots? Thanks.

Comment: @pchis1 Sure. Will edit…

Comment: Thank you very much . . . the one face at a time is where I was going wrong!

Comment: @pchis1 Yeah, I figured that out while I was editing in the screenshots. TYJ, it’s fixed! Sorry for not being clear before. :-)